# Looking for a good way to kill threads consistently fast and safe

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

This is a follow up question to [Timing inconsistency with killing thread using event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712644/timing-inconsistency-with-killing-thread-using-event)

In a nutshell I have a main thread that tries to kill a worker thread by sending it a signal.  But the worker thread can be busy and doesn't get to the kill signal until quite sometime later.  Here's the code:

```
// Main thread code
void deactivate()
{
    while (isWorkerThreadRunning)
    {
        // Problem: sometimes it spends a long time in this loop
        logDebug("deactivate: killing worker thread");
        SetEvent(killWorker);
        Sleep(20);
    }
}

// Worker thread code
DWORD WINAPI WorkerThreadProc(LPVOID arglist)
{
    isWorkerThreadRunning = true;
    logDebug("Worker thread started");
    for (bool done = false; done != true; )
    {
        HANDLE handles[3] = { killWorker, action1, action2 };
        DWORD rc = WaitForMultipleObjects(3, handles, FALSE, INFINITE);
        switch (rc)
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0: done = true; break;
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: doAction1(); break;
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2: doAction2(); break;
        default: logWarn("Unhandled wait signal");
        }
    }
    isWorkerThreadRunning = false;
    logDebug("Worker thread killed");
    return 0;
}

void doAction1()
{
    // some potentially time consuming processing

    callbackToManagedCode(arg1);  // this can take a long time too

    // some more potentially time consuming processing
}
```

The problem is doAction1() may take a long time.  I'm wondering if there's a good way for doAction1() to quit before completely done when a kill signal is sent.  The monkey wrench is there is a callback from this unmanaged code to some managed code.

I'm thinking of revising doAction1() to be:

```
void doAction1()
{
    bool done = false;
    bool part1done = false;
    bool part2done = false;
    bool part3done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        DWORD rc = WaitForSingleObject(killWorker, 20);
        switch (rc)
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0: 
            done = true; break;
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            if (!part1done)
            {
                doAction1Part1();
                part1done = true;
            }
            else if (!part2done)
            {
                callbackToManagedCode(arg1);
                part2done = true;
            }
            else if (!part3done)
            {
                doAction1Part3();
                done = true;
            }
            break;
        default: 
            logWarn("Unhandled wait signal"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

This way the kill signal will be caught sooner.  If I need it to be much sooner I can apply the same strategy and break down doAction1Part1() and doAction1Part3() in the same manner.  However, there are still 3 issues:

1) This does not help with the callbackToManagedCode().  If for some reason that call does not return the application will hang.  I tried putting try/catch block around it but that doesn't seem to help if the callback goes into neverland.

2) If the kill signal is consumed by doAction1() then it won't be caught by the main loop in worker thread.  This can be a problem if the kill signal is only issued once.

3) If doAction1Part1() and doAction1Part3() still take a long time I will need to break them down with the same strategy as doAction1().  But this can get messy quickly.

The last resort is TerminateThread().  But I don't want to go there yet.

Anyone with WINAPI expertise knows how to kill threads consistently fast and safe?

Comment: What you are doing (and were doing in your last question) is correct, and apart from implementation details, the optimal way. Do not kill threads, ever. Always let threads exit, no exceptions. If you kill threads, destructors will not be called, buffers will not be flushed, and mutexes may deadlock.

Comment: The only thing I'd do differently is use a completion port instead of an event and `WaitForMultipleObjects`. It's slightly faster, slightly easier to use, and more straightforward. When I want threads to exit, I post a code of zero with a key of zero and zero length. Each worker thread encountering that combination simply reposts it (so the others will pick it up too, one by one) and returns from the thread function. But... that is only an implementation detail, your way is perfectly good, too.

Comment: @Damon  I'm not familiar with completion port.  From your description it sounds like a volatile global variable that is accessible by both main thread and worker threads (somewhat similar to my isWorkerThreadRunning variable).  If yes that might be an elegant alternative to signal worker thread without coding WaitForSingleObject(killWorker) everywhere.

Comment: A Completion Port is not a variable, it is an event queue that asynchronous I/O operations can post events to when they are finished, but you can also post your own event to it as well.  Threads can then periodically retrieve events from the queue.

Comment: What Remy said :-)   The nice thing is, it's effectively a threadsafe queue that lets you post messages of two integers and one pointer each (key, length, and poverlapped). The OVERLAPPED pointer can be anything if you just use it for your user messages (completion port does not touch it), when used with overlapped I/O it is the structure the system uses to report back success/failure on completion. IOCP is quite nice because it works rather universally and easily (no need to write an extra threadsafe queue).

Comment: The nice thing about overlapped I/O operations is that you can use `CancelIo/Ex()` to abort them.  But if your thread is busy doing something else, that will not help you.  So if you use an IOCP to drive your thread actions, that give you some flexibility in terminating the thread quickly if it is just sitting idle waiting for an event to trigger the next action, but that is not much help if the thread is actively doing something that is blocking the thread (like the managed call).

Comment: On Linux threads can be stopped only at cancelation points for a good reason. Maybe googling "Windows cancelation point" can help. I recommend you to check some volatile variable ("should I exit") from time to time and throw exception to kill thread. Volatile is enough here.

Comment: If it helps, then within your long running function you can periodically test if the kill event is signalled by using a zero timeout. For example `if (WaitForSingleObject(killWorker, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) // time to go;` etc.